# loadURL user input Electron Javascript

Tags: javascript, electron

I want that the user's input change the loadURL sitelink (mainWindow.loadURL("https://google.com");), via the user's input in the label of search new website (searchWebsite.html), is this possible? It currently loads google.com.
(Windows 10 & newest electron version)

This is the main.js:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu } = require("electron");


let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {

  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    frame: false,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: `${__dirname}/preload.js`
    }   });

  // I want this changed to the user's input via the label createSearchWebsite   mainWindow.loadURL("https://google.com");


  mainWindow.on("closed", function() {
    mainWindow = null;   }); }


function toggleFullscreen() {
    if (mainWindow.isFullScreen()) {
        mainWindow.setFullScreen(false);
    } else {
        mainWindow.setFullScreen(true);
    } }

function createSearchWebsite(){
                                                                         addWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      width: 300,
      height: 200,
      title:'Search website',
      webPreferences: {
          nodeIntegration: true,
          contextIsolation: false 
      }    });


  addWindow.loadURL(url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'searchWebsite.html'),
      protocol: 'file:',
      slashes: true   }));

  addWindow.on('close', function(){
      addWindow = null;   }); }

function createMainMenu() {   const template = [
    {
      label: "Options",
      submenu: 
      [
        {
            label: "Quit",
            accelerator: "CmdOrCtrl+Q",
            click() {
              app.quit();
          }
        },
        {
            label: 'Toggle full screen',
            accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+F',
            click: () => {
            toggleFullscreen();
          }
        },
        {
            label: 'Search new website',
            accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+N',
            click() {
              createSearchWebsite();
          }
        },
        {
            label: 'Toggle developer tools',
            accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+I',
            click(item, focusedWindow){
              focusedWindow.toggleDevTools();
          }
        }
      ]
    }   ];

  const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template);   Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu); }


app.on("ready", () => {   createWindow();   createMainMenu(); });


app.on("window-all-closed", function() {

  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();   } });

app.on("activate", function() {

  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();   } });
```

This is the windows that comes forward if u do CTRL+N or CMD+N. This is searchWebsite.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Search website </title>
      <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form>
            <div>
                <label>Enter website</label>
                <input type="text" id="website" autofocus>
            </div>
            <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">Search website</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script src="./main.js"></script>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have nodeIntegration set to true, you can add a click handler to your button and then:

```
function onClick = () => {
  const { remote } = require('electron')
  const website = document.querySelector("#website");
  
  if(!!website){
    remote.getCurrentWindow().loadURL(website.value);
  }
}
```